# "Низкие цены", "дешёвые цены", "выгодные цены"?

Tags: семантика, грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Цена бывает низкая и высокая. А правильны ли словосочетания "дешёвая цена" и "выгодная цена"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем не подошла **"выгодная цена"** - даже не представляю. Вполне законное выражение.

**"Дешевая цена"** - тут да, есть сомнения. Было много споров, сошлись на том, что как разговорное допустимо. Аргумент противников понятен. Цена - не товар и даже не стоимость.
Ценой не торгуют - поэтому и дешевой она быть не может. Но, с другой стороны, никто же не воспринимает выражение это буквально как "цена цены" (кроме, возможно, специалистов, см. ниже). Дешевая себестоимость - дешевая стоимость - дешевая цена... Ряд вполне понятен. А "дешевая цена" - из дешевого сегмента. Не обязательно, кстати, "низкая".

Посмотрите еще вот здесь.
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=8&i=12646&t=12641

Почему я считаю, что выражение не должно выходить за рамки разговорного применения.
Тут есть одна тонкость. Экономисты и финансисты знают такое понятие как "цена денег" (даже в разных значениях, не буду здесь перегружать сторонней наукой) и при желании могут вывести из неё и "цену цены" - как, например, "цена назначения или выбора цены". Т.е. такая цена может быть дешевой или низкой в прямом смысле. Ну и еще там ряд возможных недоразумений просматривается. Так что там лучше выражаться аккуратно.
Но вне этих сфер "дешевая цена" вполне допустимо. Что и подтверждается словарями.

Comment: Спасибо!
Впечатление от всех этих меняющихся литературных норм такое: безграмотные обыватели своей не ведающей никаких норм разговорной
речью "продавливают" новые литературные нормы. Филологи на процесс  влиять не в состоянии, и вынуждены периодически вносить правки в словари, высокопарно говоря о том, что русский (любой другой) язык это живой организм.:)

Comment: Стилевое разделение языка - важная вещь, не стоит относиться к этому пренебрежительно. Обычно никто не пишет "дешевая цена", а употребляют выражение "низкая цена". Но в разговорной речи странно буде звучать " я сегодня нашел телевизор по низкой цене". Поэтому существование разных стилей - это достоинство языка, каждый  хорош на своем месте, а сочетание стилей еще Пушкин использовал в целях создания художественной выразительности.

Comment: "Дешёвая цена" я физически сказать не смогу, - ухо режет, язык не поворачивается.) Скажу, что купил недорогой телевизор.

Comment: >Спасибо! Впечатление от всех этих меняющихся...  
  
Матвей, Ваш комментарий, если убрать из него излишне негативную и эмоциональную составляющую, сводится в общем-то к давно известной и принимаемой всеми истине "Язык делают неграмотные люди". А по-другому и быть не может. Иначе он превратится в догму. "Грамотные" люди (включая филологов, коих вы помянули) слишком консервативны, чтобы принимать активное участие в изменении языковых норм.

Answer (score 4):

"Дёшевая цена" - тавтологичное выражение: дёшево то, на что установлена низкая цена, в результате получается "цена с низкой ценой".

"Выгодная цена" - нормальное выражение в контексте, из которого ясно, кому (продавцу, покупателю или обоим) эта цена выгодна.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что выражения  "выгодная цена, дешевая цена" допустимы, что следует из словаря:

ДЕШЁВЫЙ:1. Малостоящий, недорогой . Д-ые товары. Низкий (о цене). Купить по дешёвой цене.

ВЫГОДНЫЙ: 1.Приносящий, имеющий какую-л. выгоду. В-ая сделка. 2.Дающий высокую цену за товары, услуги. В. покупатель, клиент.3.Положительный, благоприятный, привлекательный для кого-л.

Выгодные цены - это, скорее,  привлекательные цены.

Comment: Вы бы хоть укаывали, из какого словаря это все.

Comment: Большой толковый словарь русского языка, гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов, на сайте "Грамота.ру".

Comment: Интересно происхождение слова "дешевый". Этимология у него не очень ясная, но наиболее вероятно, что оно происходит от древнерусского книжного глагола "десити" - находить, восходящего к греческому "десо" - найду, встречу. Соответственно, если постараться, то можно найти (встретить) нужный предмет,  или получить его даром, или хотя бы по низкой (дешевой, выгодной) цене.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с Alex ander. Дешевая цена, дорогая цена - это тавтология наподобие прейскуранта цен. Правда, Пушкин  применил выражение "...дорогою ценой откупалась." Но, что дозволено Юпитеру, то не дозволено быку.

По поводу выгодной цены я также согласен с Alex ander.

Comment: А может быть, Пушкин-Юпитер в данном случае не нарушал норму речи, а считал такое сочетание правильным в соответствии со своим безупречным языковым чутьем?

Comment: Цена - это мера средств за товар. Мера может быть либо большой (высокой), либо малой (низкой), но не дешевой. Поэтому, если придерживаться вопроса Матвея Демина, следует ответить: словосочетание "дешевая цена" не правильно. А разговорный язык чего только не допускает. Кстати, в словаре В.Даля (живого великорусского) это выражение присутствует. Прав Матвей Демин.